# How to enable printing option in print disabled pdf

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

So I have this pdf which is encrypted/password protected, in which it does not allow printing. Is there a way to change it's settings to allow printing? I tried to use Save as... and it was saved without a password but still can't be printed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [QPDF](https://qpdf.sourceforge.io/).

It is a command-line tool that is available to download [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qpdf/files/).

Once installed, you can remove restrictions on the PDF using the following command:

```
qpdf --decrypt "not_printable.pdf" "printable.pdf"
```

It will create a copy of the file called `printable.pdf`, everything is identical except for the fact that this new file can now be printed.

Comment: thank you but Im not sure if Im doing it correctly, I downloaded the file then located the bin folder, and double clicked on qpdf.exe then copy paste the one you provided except i changed it to the inputpath and outputpath of pdf and press enter and nothing happened :x

Comment: Im using the fix-qdf.exe the qpdf.exe does not load (opens then close quickly)

Comment: You should run CMD, then run the command with full paths to qpdf and the PDF file.

Comment: used CMD then typed in start pathofqpdfexe D:

Comment: it just opens and closes very quickly :x

Comment: dont type `start`, just type `pathofqpdfexe --decrypt "not_printable.pdf" "printable.pdf"` (replace the pdf filenames with your own of course)

Comment: thank you soo muchhhh was able to do so and it work, but the password was removed.

Comment: Trying to just make it printable but still password protected